# Python: error when using max() in Numpy where method for defining a new column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, ambiguous

I got an error when I used the default python max function in the Numpy where method. The goal is to obtain a new column based on the condition defined in the where method.

I used the following function:

```
def function (df):

  df["new col"]= np.where(df["col 1"]> 10, max(df["col 1"]-df["col 2"],0),0)

  return df
```

The error I got is as follows:

```
the truth value of a series is ambiguous. Use a a.empty(), a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

However, by eliminating the 0 in the max() the code would properly work. I need to to use the zero in the max function to avoid negative values.

```
 df["new col"]= np.where(df["col 1"]> 10, max(df["col 1"]-df["col 2"]),0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What causes the error is not the `np.where` function, but the `max`. In order to avoid this error, you can replace python's built-in `max` with numpy's `np.max`, or with `np.maximum`, depending on what you're trying to achieve

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame ({"col 1":[1,20,3,40],"col 2":[10,2,30,4]})
```

### Using `np.max`:

```py
df["new col"]= np.where(df["col 1"]> 10, np.maximum(df["col 1"]-df["col 2"],0),0)
```

Output:

```
   col 1  col 2  new col
0      1     10        0
1     20      2       18
2      3     30        0
3     40      4       36
```

Here the positions where col 1 > 10 receive value the max of col1 - col2 for that same position and 0 if this value is negative. The rest of the positions receive value 0.

### Using `np.maximum`:

```py
df["new col"]= np.where(df["col 1"]> 10, np.max(df["col 1"]-df["col 2"],0),0)
```

Output:

```
   col 1  col 2  new col
0      1     10        0
1     20      2       36
2      3     30        0
3     40      4       36
```

Here the positions where col 1 > 10 receive the max value of col1 - col2, while the other positions receive 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.clip(lower=0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html) for this:

```
np.where(df["col 1"]> 10, (df["col 1"]-df["col 2"]).clip(lower=0), 0)
```